# Resize a PopOver View Controller

Tags: ios, swift, uipopovercontroller, uipopover

I have a view controller that I want to present as a popover. How can I change its size?

```
    let carsViewController = CarsViewController()
    carsViewController.modalPresentationStyle = .Popover

    if let popoverPresentationController = a carsViewController.popoverPresentationController {
        popoverPresentationController.permittedArrowDirections = .Up
        popoverPresentationController.sourceView = carsButton
        presentViewController(alertsViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

It took me some time but I finally found an answer to this. It is as simple as adding the following line after initialising the view controller.

```
carsViewController.preferredContentSize = CGSize(width: 220,height:90)
```